# Android DDMS file explorer not working for Rooted Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000

Tags: android, eclipse, file, ddms, samsung-mobile

I have been playing at this for two days now. I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000 (Android 4.1.2 - hard requirement). I am trying to get the file explorer in DDMS to display in eclipse (I am using the file explorer correctly, it works fine for my Galaxy Nexus). I have tried everything from `adb root` (already runs in root) to `getprop ro.secure` (returns 1, so does my Galaxy Nexus). I have also tried the `ln -s toolbox ls` (returns 'file exists') with `chmod +x toolbox`. Toolbox is being symbolically linked correctly:

```
    lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-02-26 09:30 ls -> toolbox
    -rwxr-xr-x root     shell      134976 2008-08-01 08:00 toolbox
    (etc from ls -l from /system/bin)
```

I can do `adb shell`, `ls` and every other command fine via adb. It is just the DDMS>file explorer that will still draw a blank. I have rerooted and reflashed it incase something was wrong. I used multiple ROMS. I unrooted it. I even uninstalled BusyBox to make sure that was not conflicting (busybox runs fine on the Galaxy Nexus) and still I get nothing. I have all updated drivers and firmware installed. Is there anything else that I am missing that would not cause the DDMS file explorer to not work???

Current ROM is GloryROM_XENLs4_rev02_by_moisesfco  on Kernel version 3.0.31-9064076.

Picture as proof: [image: Samsung Galaxy GT-N7000 DDMS file explorer not displaying]

Comment: Probably some obscure issue with your custom installation - but truly, the DDMS file browser is a fairly poor and overweight tool even when it works, and if I remember correctly very sensitive to the output formatting of the device's 'ls' command.  Learning to do file operations using the command line adb tool may be a more practical way of getting the job done.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the comment but doing file operations using the command line adb tool is the slower way. My Project Manager wants to view sqllite tables from the device. Using adb would require a adb pull and push for each sqllite file. Yes that is possible, but slower. Especially when multiple developers are going to be doing this. I am aware of multiple rooted android applications that do this. But it is not prefered if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. If anyone else has the same problem. I ended up switching to the Cynogenmod 9.1 with android version 4.0.4. It works fine now, apparently the different ROMS that I used, PHIL4-cm6 and GLORYROM did not play well with the file explorer.